# Trying to sell the most batches of animals using linear programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, operations-research

I'm trying to sell the most batches of animals...

Let's say I have 200 dogs, 100 cats, and 100 ferrets.

```
Person A will give me $10 for a batch of: (1 dog, 1 cat, and 10 ferret).
Person B will give me $10 for a batch of: (1 dog, 20 cats, and 1 ferret).
Person C will give me $10 for a batch of: (20 dogs, 1 cat, and 1 ferret).


For person A, I can sell 10 batches (10 dogs, 10 cats, and 100 ferrets).
For person B, I can sell 5 batches (5 dogs, 100 cats, 5 ferrets).
For person C, I can sell 10 batches (200 dogs, 10 cats, and 10 ferrets).
```

Meaning, if I sell only to A, I'll get \$100, person B: \$50, person C: \$100.

**BUT!** I can actually sell more batches i.e. 9 batches to A and 9 batches to C.

If I sell 9 batches to person A (I'll use 9 dogs, 9 cats, and 90 ferrets), then I can also sell 9 batches to person C (using 18 dogs, 9 cats, and 9 ferrets).

I sell A:9 and C:9, I get the best income and most batches sold.

This is probably extremely simple in terms of optimization and a simple matrix, but it's been a while since algebra.

I obviously don't want to try every possible combination and see which gives me the most money.

**Question: Assuming that each batch always has the same income, is there a way to find out which combination of batches A/B/C will give the highest yield?**

Comment: I hope you don't mind - I added the tag linear-programming to this question. This is actually what you are trying to do. You are correct that it's fairly straightforward once you know what term to google.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll I figured it's extremely simple, but it's been too long since I was in school.  If someone could just point me to a wiki or any kind of article with something related, I'm sure I could piece it together.  Maybe lol

Comment: Here's [the first hit on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-32jcGMpD2Q) for "linear programming." It's only 15 minutes and seems to cover all the information you'd need for this sort of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still suggest watching [the tutorial video I linked in the comments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-32jcGMpD2Q) to understand how linear programming works. That being said, you can formulate your problem as trying to maximize

$$Profit=10A+10B+10C$$

subject to the constraints on your number of dogs to sell ($A+B+20C \leq 200$), number of cats to sell ($A+20B+C \leq 100$), number of ferrets to sell ($10A+B+C \leq 100$), and that the number of batches sold must be positive ($A\geq0$, $B\geq0$, and $C\geq0$).

Linear programming tells us that the maximum occurs on a point at the endpoints of the polyhedron formed by all of our constraints. Integer programming tells us that the maximum will be an integer point inside the endpoints (if they're not already integers). Thus, we only have to check a few endpoints.

In your case:

$$\begin{aligned}
(A,B,C) = (0,0,0)&\text{ yields Profit}=\$0\\
(A,B,C) = (10,0,0)&\text{ yields Profit}=\$100\\
(A,B,C) = (0,5,0)&\text{ yields Profit}=\$50\\
(A,B,C) = (0,0,10)&\text{ yields Profit}=\$100\\
(A,B,C) = (9.5,4.5,0)&\text{ yields Profit}=\$130\\
(A,B,C) = (9.0,0,9.5)&\text{ yields Profit}=\$180\\
(A,B,C) = (0,4.5,9.7)&\text{ yields Profit}=\$130\\
(A,B,C) = (8.7,4.1,9.4)&\text{ yields Profit}=\$210\\
\end{aligned}$$

Therefore, selling 8 batches to person A, 4 batches to person B, and 9 batches to person C will yield \$210, only requiring 192 dogs, 97 cats, and 93 ferrets.

Comment: Yep. I already watched it and was trying to work out the math. Now I have to find how to get polyhedron intersections.  ps. It's hard to sell 4.5 cats and 9.7 ferrets... but some might try ;)

Comment: I'll be honest, I just typed `Solve[{a+b+20c==200,a+20b+c==100,10a+b+c==100}]//N` into WolframAlpha so that I wouldn't have to deal with the messy math myself!

Comment: Solving systems of equations is much easier.  I have no problems with that. How did you arrive at the 9.5, 4.5, 0; 9.0, 0, 9.5; and 0, 4.5, 9.7 test points?  They don't appear to be solutions to the s.o.e.  Wolfram only gives a single set of points, since it's a linear set. Not sure how the others were generated.

Comment: @David The first solution is from selling to none of the buyers. The next 3 are from selling to one of the buyers. The next 3 are selling to 2 of the buyers. The last one is from selling to all 3 of the buyers. For instance, if I plan to buy 0 from person C then my equations become $A+B\leq200$, $A+20B\leq100$,$10A+B\leq100$. Noting that the inequality $A+B\leq200$ adds nothing compared to the other two inequalities, I used `Solve[{a+20b==100,10a+b==100}]//N` with WolframAlpha. It's a lot easier to draw the systems of inequalities out and find the intersection points that way...

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Let the integer decision variables $x_1, x_2, x_3 \geq 0$ denote the number of batches of animals sold to customers $A$, $B$ and $C$, respectively. Since we have a finite number of dogs, cats and ferrets, we have three inequality constraints

$$\begin{array}{cc} x_1 + x_2 + 20 x_3 \leq 200\\ x_1 + 20 x_2 + x_3 \leq 100\\ 10 x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \leq 100\end{array}$$

Each batch that is sold brings in $\$10$. Hence, the total revenue is $10 x_1 + 10 x_2 + 10 x_3$. Assuming that our goal is to maximize revenue, we have the following **integer linear program**

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & 10 x_1 + 10 x_2 + 10 x_3\\ \text{subject to} & x_1 + x_2 + 20 x_3 \leq 200\\ & x_1 + 20 x_2 + x_3 \leq 100\\ & 10 x_1 + x_2 + x_3 \leq 100\\ & x_1, x_2, x_3 \geq 0\\ & x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \mathbb{Z}\end{array}$$

Observing the inequality constraints, we conclude that

$$x_1 \leq 10 \qquad \qquad x_2 \leq 5 \qquad \qquad x_3 \leq 10$$

Hence, the feasible region is a subset of

$$\{0,1,\dots,10\} \times \{0,1,\dots,5\} \times \{0,1,\dots,10\}$$

whose cardinality is only $(1+5) \cdot (1+10)^2 = 726$. One can use brute force to find the optimal solution. Using Haskell,

```
λ let triples =  [ (x1,x2,x3) | x1 <- [0,1..10], x2 <- [0,1..5], x3 <- [0,1..10] ]
λ let f (x1,x2,x3) = 10 * (x1 + x2 + x3)
λ let g1 (x1,x2,x3) = (x1 + x2 + 20*x3 <= 200)
λ let g2 (x1,x2,x3) = (x1 + 20*x2 + x3 <= 100)
λ let g3 (x1,x2,x3) = (10*x1 + x2 + x3 <= 100)
λ let triples' = filter g1 triples
λ let triples'' = filter g2 triples'
λ let triples''' = filter g3 triples''
λ maximum $ map f triples'''
210
λ filter (\(x1,x2,x3)->(f (x1,x2,x3) == 210)) triples'''
[(8,4,9)]
```

The optimal sale is $(8,4,9)$, which yields a revenue of $\$210$.

Comment: Thanks. I like how you explained it, but I'm avoiding brute force. It only works for smaller quantities. If I have more dogs/cats/ferrets, it becomes unfeasible.

Comment: @David It's not merely a matter of how many animals you have, it's also how many customers you have. You can obviously use a linear programming solver, obtain the LP solution over the reals, and then round the solution to an integer solution.

Comment: Yep, but I'm trying to understand it fundamentally and not rely on compumagic. :)